# Passing type variable when instantiating a generic class

Tags: java, generics

Can someone explain what the different between these two instantiations of the `ArrayList` class?

```
List<Integer> intList = new  ArrayList();
List<Integer> intList = new  ArrayList<Integer>();
```

I knew that the compiler erase the type variable, i.e. `Integer`, when compile it to bytecode and the above example both works exactly the same. I wonder if there is any benefit at all to pass the type variable (`Integer`) on the right hand side since it is already declared on the left? As far as I can find on the web, they all uses the latter one but I cannot see any reason why I should declare it twice on both sides.

Comment: There is the diamond operator (`<>`) Project Coin feature, which I think is in JDK7, that allows you to write `List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>();`. The algorithm for determining type works much the same as for generic methods.

Comment: I'm looking forwards to the new features in JDK7. This is a good one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version without the type parameter results in a warning, because it might not be type-safe. In your case this is not a problem because the list is empty, but in general it is. For example

```
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
stringList.add("foo");
List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList(stringList); // Warning about unchecked conversion
int i = intList.get(0); // Oops, throws a ClassCastException
```

So to ensure type safety it is best to get rid of the warning by adding the type parameters everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

They're two different things. The left side is the type of your variable. The right side is the type of the object you're creating. The compiler will first create the object using the type you gave it on the right side, then assign the reference to the variable on your left side.

In your case, there is no difference since an ArrayList has the same constructor in all cases. However:

- In other classes, the constructor may behave differently based on the specific type you're providing.
- You'll make it easier on the compiler if you match the type. In the first version, the compiler will have to assign an object of type `ArrayList` to a variable that expects a `List<Integer>` type. In some cases, you may get a warning because the types don't clearly match up.

Answer (score 0):

You probably wanted the difference between :

```
List intList = new  ArrayList();
List<Integer> intList = new  ArrayList<Integer>();
```

They are both same in runtime. But there are big differences in compile time.